# Make java check array equal

Tags: java, arrays

I'm pretty new to writing code, I've been given a Java task to write a program with two arrays of the same size, and the user is entering values into them. Then the program runs and checks that both arrays have the same values.
For example: array1 {1,2,3,4,5} and array2 {3,2,5,4,1} are considered equal.
But if the second array has a different number (array2 {3,2,6,4,1}) it will be considered that they are not equal.
When the two arrays are equal but the values are not located in the same index, the second array should be changed to the index on the right.

Hope I understand, I wrote code anyway but I was really confused.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exe_3_sameOrNot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int ARR_SIZE = 5;
        int num1, num2;
        int i, j, k;

        int[] firstArr = new int[ARR_SIZE];
        int[] secArr = new int[ARR_SIZE];

        for (i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter first 5 numbers ");
            firstArr[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < secArr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter sec 5 numbers ");
            secArr[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        int len = firstArr.length;
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (firstArr[j] == secArr[j]) {
                System.out.print(firstArr[j] + "\n" + secArr[j]);
            } else {
                for (k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                    if (k == len) {
                        k = k * 0;

                    }
                    secArr[k] = secArr[k + 1];
                }
                System.out.print(secArr[k]);
            }
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just look for collections in java and use containsAll method

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

A "naive" implementation would be to use nested loops to compare each element in `array1` to each element of `array2` providing that the lengths of both arrays are equal:

```java
static boolean arraysEqual(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    
    if (a1.length != a2.length) { // different lengths, could not be "equal"
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0, n = a1.length; i < n; i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < n && !found; j++) {
            if (a1[i] == a2[j]) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) { // missing element detected
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, this solution works well when there are no duplicates in the input array.
That is, for the inputs below the result would be `true`:

```
int[] a3 = {4, 3, 2, 2, 2};
int[] a4 = {3, 3, 2, 4, 2};
```

If it is needed to make sure that both arrays contain equal counts of different elements, it may be better to sort the input arrays and check if all the sorted elements are equal:

```java
static boolean arraysEqual2(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    
    if (a1.length != a2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    Arrays.sort(a1);
    Arrays.sort(a2);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Tests:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] a2 = {4, 3, 2, 1, 5};
    int[] a3 = {4, 3, 2, 2, 2};
    int[] a4 = {3, 2, 3, 4, 2};
    int[] a5 = {3, 2, 4, 3, 2};
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1) + " EQ " + Arrays.toString(a2) + "? nested: " + arraysEqual(a1, a2) + "; sorted: " + arraysEqual2(a1, a2));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1) + " EQ " + Arrays.toString(a3) + "? nested: " + arraysEqual(a1, a3) + "; sorted: " + arraysEqual2(a1, a3));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a2) + " EQ " + Arrays.toString(a3) + "? nested: " + arraysEqual(a2, a3) + "; sorted: " + arraysEqual2(a2, a3));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a2) + " EQ " + Arrays.toString(a4) + "? nested: " + arraysEqual(a2, a4) + "; sorted: " + arraysEqual2(a2, a4));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a3) + " EQ " + Arrays.toString(a4) + "? nested: " + arraysEqual(a3, a4) + "; sorted: " + arraysEqual2(a3, a4));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a5) + " EQ " + Arrays.toString(a4) + "? nested: " + arraysEqual(a5, a4) + "; sorted: " + arraysEqual2(a5, a4));
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] EQ [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]? nested: true; sorted: true
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] EQ [4, 3, 2, 2, 2]? nested: false; sorted: false
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] EQ [2, 2, 2, 3, 4]? nested: false; sorted: false
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] EQ [3, 2, 3, 4, 2]? nested: false; sorted: false
[2, 2, 2, 3, 4] EQ [2, 2, 3, 3, 4]? nested: true; sorted: false
[3, 2, 4, 3, 2] EQ [2, 2, 3, 3, 4]? nested: true; sorted: true
```

Answer (score 0):

*short and sweet with lambda*

b1 and b2 are the arrays a1 and a2 sorted:

```
int[] b1 = Arrays.stream( a1 ).sorted().toArray();
int[] b2 = Arrays.stream( a2 ).sorted().toArray();
```

check whether both arrays are of the same length and all the numbers in the corresponding positions on both arrays are equal:

```
System.out.println( "is equal: "
    + ((b1.length == b2.length) && IntStream.range( 0, b1.length )
      .allMatch( i -> b1[i] == b2[i] ) ));
```

*that's it*